# Delete file after a required number of days

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdate

In my iphone application, i want to delete files automatically after a particular number of days from the creation of the file.The number of days after the file are to be deleted can be given by the user.I store the Date and Time of creation of file. How to perform this? All valuable suggestions are appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when user run the app you check with the date and delete the file by using

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:myPath error:NULL];
```

Comment: But i want the deletion to be automatically done with the number of days specified by me.How to do this comparison automatically.A sample code will be of really great help. Thanks.

Comment: May be you can go for the Local Notifications.  But it only works for 4.0 or later

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at the [local] notification service, just handling the notification under the hood, without a user alert...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4